# What's the difference between vcvarsall.bat and bin/vcvars32.bat?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, visual-c++

In the directory, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC`, ther are two`.bat` files:

- `./vcvarsall.bat`
- `bin/vcvars32.bat`

Running each one gives the same message:

> Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

What is the purpose of each, and when would I choose to use each one?

Below is the contents of each bat file:
**vcvarsall.bat:**

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" goto x86
if not "%2" == "" goto usage

if /i %1 == x86       goto x86
if /i %1 == amd64     goto amd64
if /i %1 == x64       goto amd64
if /i %1 == ia64      goto ia64
if /i %1 == x86_amd64 goto x86_amd64
if /i %1 == x86_ia64  goto x86_ia64
goto usage

:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
goto :eof

:amd64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
goto :eof

:ia64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\ia64\vcvars64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\ia64\vcvars64.bat"
goto :eof

:x86_amd64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\x86_amd64\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
goto :eof

:x86_ia64
if not exist "%~dp0bin\x86_ia64\vcvarsx86_ia64.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\x86_ia64\vcvarsx86_ia64.bat"
goto :eof

:usage
echo Error in script usage. The correct usage is:
echo     %0 [option]
echo where [option] is: x86 ^| ia64 ^| amd64 ^| x86_amd64 ^| x86_ia64
echo:
echo For example:
echo     %0 x86_ia64
goto :eof

:missing
echo The specified configuration type is missing.  The tools for the
echo configuration might not be installed.
goto :eof
```

**bin/vcvars32.bat:**

```
@echo Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

@call :GetVSCommonToolsDir
@if "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"=="" goto error_no_VS100COMNTOOLSDIR

@call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat" 32bit No64bit

@if "%VSINSTALLDIR%"=="" goto error_no_VSINSTALLDIR
@if "%FrameworkDir32%"=="" goto error_no_FrameworkDIR32
@if "%FrameworkVersion32%"=="" goto error_no_FrameworkVer32
@if "%Framework35Version%"=="" goto error_no_Framework35Version

@set FrameworkDir=%FrameworkDir32%
@set FrameworkVersion=%FrameworkVersion32%

@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" (
    @set "PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;%WindowsSdkDir%bin;%PATH%"
    @set "INCLUDE=%WindowsSdkDir%include;%INCLUDE%"
    @set "LIB=%WindowsSdkDir%lib;%LIB%"
)

@rem
@rem Root of Visual Studio IDE installed files.
@rem
@set DevEnvDir=%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\IDE\

@rem PATH
@rem ----
@if exist "%VSINSTALLDIR%Team Tools\Performance Tools" (
    @set "PATH=%VSINSTALLDIR%Team Tools\Performance Tools;%PATH%"
)
@if exist "%ProgramFiles%\HTML Help Workshop" set PATH=%ProgramFiles%\HTML Help Workshop;%PATH%
@if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\HTML Help Workshop" set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\HTML Help Workshop;%PATH%
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%VCPackages" set PATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%VCPackages;%PATH%
@set PATH=%FrameworkDir%%Framework35Version%;%PATH%
@set PATH=%FrameworkDir%%FrameworkVersion%;%PATH%
@set PATH=%VSINSTALLDIR%Common7\Tools;%PATH%
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%BIN" set PATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%BIN;%PATH%
@set PATH=%DevEnvDir%;%PATH%

@if exist "%VSINSTALLDIR%VSTSDB\Deploy" (
    @set "PATH=%VSINSTALLDIR%VSTSDB\Deploy;%PATH%"
)

@if not "%FSHARPINSTALLDIR%" == "" (
    @set "PATH=%FSHARPINSTALLDIR%;%PATH%"
)

@rem INCLUDE
@rem -------
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\INCLUDE" set INCLUDE=%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\INCLUDE;%INCLUDE%
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%INCLUDE" set INCLUDE=%VCINSTALLDIR%INCLUDE;%INCLUDE%

@rem LIB
@rem ---
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\LIB" set LIB=%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\LIB;%LIB%
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%LIB" set LIB=%VCINSTALLDIR%LIB;%LIB%

@rem LIBPATH
@rem -------
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\LIB" set LIBPATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC\LIB;%LIBPATH%
@if exist "%VCINSTALLDIR%LIB" set LIBPATH=%VCINSTALLDIR%LIB;%LIBPATH%
@set LIBPATH=%FrameworkDir%%Framework35Version%;%LIBPATH%
@set LIBPATH=%FrameworkDir%%FrameworkVersion%;%LIBPATH%

@goto end

@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetVSCommonToolsDir
@set VS100COMNTOOLS=
@call :GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper32 HKLM > nul 2>&1
@if errorlevel 1 call :GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper32 HKCU > nul 2>&1
@if errorlevel 1 call :GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper64  HKLM > nul 2>&1
@if errorlevel 1 call :GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper64  HKCU > nul 2>&1
@exit /B 0

:GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper32
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0"') DO (
    @if "%%i"=="10.0" (
        @SET "VS100COMNTOOLS=%%k"
    )
)
@if "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"=="" exit /B 1
@SET "VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%Common7\Tools\"
@exit /B 0

:GetVSCommonToolsDirHelper64
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0"') DO (
    @if "%%i"=="10.0" (
        @SET "VS100COMNTOOLS=%%k"
    )
)
@if "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"=="" exit /B 1
@SET "VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%Common7\Tools\"
@exit /B 0

@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------
:error_no_VS100COMNTOOLSDIR
@echo ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
@goto end

:error_no_VSINSTALLDIR
@echo ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS installation.
@goto end

:error_no_FrameworkDIR32
@echo ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the .NET Framework 32bit installation.
@goto end

:error_no_FrameworkVer32
@echo ERROR: Cannot determine the version of the .NET Framework 32bit installation.
@goto end

:error_no_Framework35Version
@echo ERROR: Cannot determine the .NET Framework 3.5 version.
@goto end

:end
```

Comment: How does the code in the two scripts differ?

Comment: @SomethingDark added file contents.

Comment: The first one determines which batch file to use and calls the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use vcvarsall.bat, as it determines, based on the parameter value you pass in, which vcvars*.bat file to call.

Snippet from vcvarsall.bat:

```
:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
goto :eof
```